# How to use jenkins ssh-steps plugin to copy a remote directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Im trying to copy a remote directory using jenkins [ssh-steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin) plugin. But when i ran the script i get

```
4: not supported to get directory /home/jenkins/app-performance/target/gatling
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:930)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:892)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$get.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.operation.SftpOperations$_getFile_closure1.doCall(SftpOperations.groovy:39)
at org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.operation.SftpOperations$_getFile_closure1.doCall(SftpOperations.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
```

my pipeline code is

```
stage('Download report'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sshGet remote: remote, from: "app-performance/target/gatling" , into: "${env.WORKSPACE}/app-performance/"
                }
            }
        }
```

according to the plugin readme it should be possible to download directories using sshGet. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code worked for me in my scripted pipeline:

```
def source='./deployments/logs/'
def destination='deployments/'
sshGet remote: remote, from: source, into: destination, override: true
```

At the end i could copy the log directory from the remote into the node.

Comment: I'd suggest you to revisit the answer and to leverage the different formatting options offered. The code section will look better if you use the code tags.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, I can assume that the source directory (from argument) does not exist on the remote server, because the directory is relative, which simply resolves to: `'~/deployments/logs/'`. Amend it to a full directory.

Also, add  this line to your configuration:

```
remote.fileTransfer = 'scp' //"scp" must be in lowercase, uppercase will only throw another error
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
    Map remote = [:]
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'remotessh', passwordVariable: 'pwd', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
        remote.name = "test"
        remote.host = 'your remote address or IP'
        remote.user = "${ user }"
        remote.password = "${ pwd }"
        remote.fileTransfer = 'scp'
        remote.allowAnyHosts = true //optional, but safe to use
    }
def source='~/app-performance/target/gatling' //file or directory path from the remote node.
def destination="${env.WORKSPACE}/app-performance/" // file or directory path on current workspace.
sshGet remote: remote, from: source, into: destination, override: true
```